# Error while running cron job on PHP

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

While running cron job on php cpanel it cause error and when I recieved email there only print this **"No input file specified."**
here is the cron settings on cpanel.
 /usr/bin/php -q /home/occ/wp-content/projectname/scriptFile.php

Thanks

Comment: Double check if the path provided by you to the script file is right.

Comment: provide exact error what it prints.

Comment: yeah it is the right path /occ/wp-content/projectname/scriptFile.php also i run this path to browser and there it is running fine.

Comment: When i received email i seen only this content "No input file specified."

Comment: I just ask you guyz Is this is the right syntax to set the cron job  /usr/bin/php -q /home/occ/wp-content/projectname/scriptFile.php Thanks

Comment: @QubaishBhatti - the syntax looks OK. Can you cut and paste that command and run it on the command line? Does it work then?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @andrewsi actually I am not my own server, thats why i cant run on command line. I have only access to cpanel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is right syntax " /usr/bin/php -q /home/occ/wp-content/projectname/scriptFile.php" but you need to make sure correct path and permissions.

Comment: Well the issue is solved the only problem is the wrong path. Thanks